# How do I send a NavigationCommand to a control?

Tags: wpf, flowdocumentreader

FlowDocumentReader doesn't have a GoToPage method, but it supports NavigationCommands.GoToPage RoutedUICommand.

How do I send NavigationCommands.GoToPage with parameter (for example: 1) to my FlowDocumentReader **from within my code** (not using xaml)?

Thanks,
   Yariv

Edited:
Thanks! But though I can send the command with your help, I don't get the expected results. This is the code (and I tried to use FirstPage instead of PreviousPage too):

```
if (NavigationCommands.PreviousPage.CanExecute(null, this) == true)
{
    NavigationCommands.PreviousPage.Execute(null, this);
}
```

Even though the if statement is true and the inner code is being executed, the FlowDocumentReader stays in the last page...

Answer (score 0):

```
FlowDocumentReader flowDoc;
...
NavigationCommands.GoToPage.Execute("my parameter", flowDoc);
```

Comment: Thanks! But though I can send the command with your help, I don't get the expected results. This is the code (and I tried to use FirstPage instead of PreviousPage too):

if (NavigationCommands.PreviousPage.CanExecute(null, this) == true) {
    NavigationCommands.PreviousPage.Execute(null, this);
}

Even though the if statement is true and the inner code is being executed, the FlowDocumentReader stays in the last page...